# Access Query based on a form with multiple checkboxs

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

I can't seem to find any answers here for my specific problem. Maybe it's because I don't know what I'm looking for...

Anyway, I have an Access form that has about 30 checkboxes for each live facility we have and I need to run a query (which works perfectly) based on what boxes are ticked and a begin and end date which are also on the form.

This is the SQL I have (generated by the Query Wizard) that shows every single facility for every single date.

```
TRANSFORM Count(tblFilesProcessed.[File Name]) AS [CountOfFile Name] 
SELECT tblFilesProcessed.[Fac Alpha], tblFilesProcessed.[File Date], Count(tblFilesProcessed.[File Name]) AS [Total Of File Name]
FROM tblFilesProcessed
GROUP BY tblFilesProcessed.[Fac Alpha], tblFilesProcessed.[File Date]
PIVOT tblFilesProcessed.[File Type];
```

I need to be able to pick and choose what I want the report to show. Right now it shows Facility01 all the way through Facility30 for dates going back to March. I need to be able to tick a box for Facility04, Facility 15, and Facility 20 for the past week. Or Facility 03, 21, 22, 23, 24.

Comment: If query 'works perfectly', what is issue? There is no filter criteria in query. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. 30 checkboxes is a lot. I suspect data is not normalized.

Comment: Yes, the query works, but I need to be able to pick and choose what I want the report to show. 

Right now it shows Facility01 all the way through Facility30 for dates going back to March. I need to be able to tick a box for Facility04, Facility 15, and Facility 20 for the past week.

Comment: Edit question as requested. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: Thank you for the resources. I'm sure they will help me understand Access better.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is to use VBA to look at the controls on the form, and build up a modified SQL statement which you will then set to be the query's `.SQL`. Something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdQuery_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strSQL1 As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    strSQL1 = "TRANSFORM Count(F.[File Name]) AS [CountOfFile Name] " _
        & " SELECT F.[Fac Alpha], F.[File Date], Count(F.[File Name]) AS [Total Of File Name] " _
        & " FROM tblFilesProcessed AS F "
    strSQL2 = " GROUP BY F.[Fac Alpha], F.[File Date] " _
        & " PIVOT F.[File Type];"
    If Me!chkFac1 = True Then strWhere = strWhere & "'Fac1',"
    If Me!chkFac2 = True Then strWhere = strWhere & "'Fac2',"
    If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
        strWhere = " AND F.[Fac Alpha] IN(" & Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1) & ") "
    End If
    If IsDate(Me!txtFrom) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND F.[File Date]>=" & Format(Me!txtFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
    End If
    If IsDate(Me!txtTo) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND F.[File Date]<=" & Format(Me!txtTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
    End If
    If Left(strWhere, 4) = " AND" Then
        strWhere = " WHERE " & Mid(strWhere, 5)
    End If
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryFilesProcessed").SQL = strSQL1 & strWhere & strSQL2
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmFilesProcessed!cmdQuery_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

I would suggest that rather than using 30 checkboxes, a multi-select list box would be better, as it allows for future proofing - indeed, you could set its `.RowSource` to be the list of unique Facility values from the table.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not a coder or database admin but have been thrust into the position by mgmt. I don't understand this code, but I will try to decipher it. Thanks again.